# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement Push Notifications in my app through Firebase.

I've followed the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#register_for_remote_notifications, and permission gets granted. I get an FCM token, but the test message does not work.

I found a debug guide that suggested I manually get call these methods, but `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` or `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` never gets called.

Obviously, I assumed this was a code or config issue, but I've tried ruling them out with no such luck. When I download the iOS sample app here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging/

Everything works great. I change no code, just the bundle Id, and GoogleServices-Info.plist. I get an APNs returned, and the same push works great.

So, I then copied the entire AppDelegate.swift to my project. Same code, same App Id, Push notifications enabled, Automatically Manage signing. It does not work, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` was not called.

The only differences that I can find are as follows:
• The sample app is not using SwiftUI. I'm forwarding the AppDelegate with UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor, and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is being called just fine
• I'm using Swift Package Manager instead of CocoaPods. Code compiles fine, and no error messages.

Here's what I know is the same:
• Matching App delegates. Copy/pasted. No other code related to Notifications is in the app
• Matching App Capabilities
• Matching App Id, GoogleServiceInfo.plist
• Matching "Automatically Manage Signing"

At this point, I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions of other things to check would be great. What would cause `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` not to be called?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: If the above is true, is there something else I can check? In the meantime, I can try and create something

Comment: That's a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It ended up being that a SwiftUI app did not support method swizzling by default. Instead, Firebase was trying to intercept the method unsuccessfully, resulting in the original method not being called

Disabling swizzling with the recommended flag and then sending it manually fixed the issue.